# rdflib add OWL:imports statement

Tags: protege, rdflib

I'm trying to add an OWL:imports statement in my graph

```
g.add((URIRef(my_iri), OWL.imports, URIRef("http://www.cidoc-crm.org/cidoc-crm/")))
```

The rdf is generated as expected:

```
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="myIRI">
  <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://www.cidoc-crm.org/cidoc-crm/"/>
</owl:Ontology>
```

However, Protégé shows an empty "direct import" section.